# Guardar partes de un String en variables usando expresiones regulares

Tags: java, string, regex

Necesito guardar partes de una String en distintas variables usando una sola expresión regular, la cadena es la siguiente y puede variar, pero la estructura siempre va a ser la misma (esta linea esta almacenada en la variable strLineProcess):

```
Skype.exe pid: 1404 WATCHOUT\tofetopo
```

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
final String regex = "^(\\S*)";
final String processDetails = strLineProcess;
String processName = null;
String processID = null;
String computerName = null;
String currentUser = null;

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(processDetails);

if (matcher.find()) {
    processName = matcher.group(1);
    processID = matcher.group(2);
    computerName = matcher.group(3);
    currentUser = matcher.group(4);
}
```

La expresión regular en la variable regex coincide correctamente el nombre del proceso, pero no se como concatenar expresiones regulares para guardar las siguientes partes del String. Por ejemplo la expresión regular `((\S*)+([0-9]))` coincide con el processID (que en este ejemplo seria 1404), pero necesito concatenarla con la primera expresión para tener todo en una, al igual que deberia hacer con computerName y currentUser, y aqui es donde estoy perdido. Alguna idea?

La salida esperada en este ejemplo es:

```
processName = Skype.exe
processID = 1404
computerName = WATCHOUT
currentUser = tofetopo
```

El nombre del proceso puede ser cualquiera hasta el primer espacio, el processID sólo números, computerName siempre aparece justo después del processID y hasta antes de la `"\"`, y el currentUser todo lo que viene despues de la `"\"`.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor si indicas la entrada y la salida esperada. Recuerda que también puedes usar `String#split` que divide una cadena en un arreglo de cadenas basado en un regex.

Comment: Pues el sentido es guardar cada parte en una variable, como acabo de indicar en el ejemplo de salida, y evitar guardar "pid:" para quedarme solo con el ID del proceso. Tambien separar el computerName del currentUser que aparece todo junto en el String

Comment: Exacto, el nombre del proceso puede ser cualquiera hasta el primer espacio, el processID solo numeros, computerName siempre aparece justo despues del processID y hasta antes de la "\", y el currentUser todo lo que viene despues de la "\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
^(\S+) pid: (\d+) ([^\\\s]+)\\(.+)
```

- `^` - Inicio del texto
- `(\S+)` - Caracteres que no son espacios en blanco, capturado en grupo 1
- `pid:` - coincide con el texto literal
- `(\d+)` - Dígitos, capturado en grupo 2
- `([^\\\s]+)` - Caracteres que no son `\` ni espacios en blanco, capturado en grupo 3
- `\\` - Coincide con un `\` literal
- `(.+)` - 1 o más caracteres, capturado en grupo 4

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "^(\\S+) pid: (\\d+) ([^\\\\\\s]+)\\\\(.+)";
final String processDetails = "Skype.exe pid: 1404 WATCHOUT\\tofetopo";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(processDetails);

if (matcher.find()) {
    processName = matcher.group(1);
    processID = matcher.group(2);
    computerName = matcher.group(3);
    currentUser = matcher.group(4);
}
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/6gVdBI

Comment: Funciona perfectamente y me quedaron bien claros los conceptos. Esta es la salida de mi aplicación Java: The process currently using your cam is: 
YouCam.exe pid: 11640 WATCHOUT\tofetopo

YouCam.exe
11640
WATCHOUT
tofetopo
Data successfully inserted into database! Graciass!!!